# why every time new xib file is loading?why it is not replace the previous one?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xib

my vc code is look like this.here the showClick function is an button tapped function.clicking this button I want to load a xib file.which is a music player.

```
//
//  PlayerTestOneVC.swift
//  rapapediaPlayer
//
//  Created by rumy hasan on 9/3/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 rumyhasan. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Jukebox


var viewOne = UIView()
var viewTow = UIView()
var playerMainView: UIView?
var viewOfAll: UIView?

class PlayerTestOneVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    @IBAction func showClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if let keywindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{
            if var viewtag = keywindow.viewWithTag(50){
                viewtag.removeFromSuperview()

            }
            if let player = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Player", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? Player{
                viewOne = player.viewOne
                viewTow = player.viewTow
                //player.bellowBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(change), for: .touchUpInside)
                //playerMainView = player

                player.ppBtnOut.isHidden = true

                player.frame = keywindow.frame
                playerMainView = player
                viewOfAll = player
                viewOfAll?.tag = 50
                playerMainView = player
                keywindow.addSubview(viewOfAll!)

            }


        }
    }



}
```

My xib file looks like this.

[image]

after clicking below the view looks like this

[image]

it's ok, working properly and play songs but now if I again click the show button it create a new view upper the existing view and both player play their own audio and I can hear the tow at a same time but I need to replace the first one with the new one.how can I do that?

my xib file below button tapped code is here.

```
@IBAction func belowClick(_ sender: Any) {
    if dropDown{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            viewOfAll?.frame = (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame)!
        }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in

        })

    }else{
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            viewOfAll?.frame = self.viewOne.frame
            viewOfAll?.frame = CGRect(x: 0 , y: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame.height)! - 70, width: (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.frame.width)!, height: 70)
        })

    }
    dropDown = !dropDown
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `player` starts playing audio files in an other thread as it should. Whenever you click on the show button, you create a new `player` without stopping previous `player`. You are just removing it's view  by `viewtag.removeFromSuperview()` because of that it continues playing the previous and new audio files together.

I think, you can create a `stop` function and call it before removing it's view.

Comment: But I can also see the previous view here when I click below I can slightly  show it.